# How to pass selected text of checkbox to action result on razor page?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on asp.net core razor page . I pass selected id as array success

but my issue selected text value for check box not passed or displayed

Issue happen on this line `selectedClassText.push($(this).next('label').text());`

when debug action result `string[] classidsText` it display null .

Exactly i need to pass selected text beside checkbox as array.

razor page .cs that get class id text

```
    public JsonResult OnGetSubAccountClassName(string[] classIds,string[] classidsText)
{
    var assetsSubAccountName = _IAssetsService.GetJdeAssetSubAccountClassName(classIds);
    AssetCountGeneration.JDEAssetSubAccountClassNameDetails = assetsSubAccountName;
    return new JsonResult(assetsSubAccountName);
}
```

from jQuery ajax on page cshtml i send selected displayed text by `selectedClassText`

```
    $(document).on('change', '.classCheckbox', function () {
      var selectedClassIds = [];
      var selectedClassText = [];
$('.classCheckbox:checked').each(function () {
    selectedClassIds.push($(this).val());
    selectedClassText.push($(this).next('label').text());
});
      console.log("selected items" + selectedClassIds)
      if (selectedClassIds.length > 0) {
          $.ajax({
              url: '?handler=SubAccountClassName',
              type: 'GET',
              traditional: true,
              data: { classIds: selectedClassIds,classidsText:selectedClassText },
              success: function (response) {
                  $('#subClassesList').empty();
                  $('#subClassesContainer').show();
                 
                  var subClassesContainer = $('<div data-class-id="' + selectedClassIds + '"></div>');
                  $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                      $(subClassesContainer).append('<input type="checkbox" class="subclassCheckbox" name="selectedSubClasses" value="' + item.subClassAccountId + '" /> ' + item.subClassAccountName + '<br />');
                  });
                  $('#subClassesList').append(subClassesContainer);
              }
          });
```

**Updated post**

I try code below but not worked so how to solve this issue
console.log() and it give me null

when create checkbox list before make change event

i create it as below

```
$('#btnDisplay').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var dropdown = $('#accountclassname-select');
      dropdown.empty();
    
      $.ajax({
          url: '?handler=AccountClassName',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (response) {
              $('#classesContainer').show();
              $('#classesList').html(''); // Clear existing classes
              $('#classesList').append('<input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="0" /> All <br />');
              $.each(response, function (i, classes) {
                  $('#classesList').append('<input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="' + classes.classAccountId + '" /> ' + classes.classAccountName + '<br />');
              });
             
          }
      });
  });
```

**Important notes**

I don't have label to append text on it

i create list as below

```
$(subClassesContainer).append('<input type="checkbox" class="subclassCheckbox" name="selectedSubClasses" value="' + item.subClassAccountId + '" /> ' + item.subClassAccountName + '<br />');
                      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Like This**

You can pass the label text with custom attributes in the input like this

```
<input type="checkbox" class="classCheckbox" value="' + classes.classAccountId + '" data-label="'+ classes.classAccountName +'"/> ' + classes.classAccountName + '<br />
```

After that you can get the value of custom attribute (label text) like this in your loop and push its value in array

```
var selectedText = $(this).attr("data-label");
selectedClassText.push(selectedText);
```

Comment: not working i check on console.log not give me any this it give me null i try by two ways not worked

Comment: I have just edited the my answer given above, you can take guidance from it and do it according to your business logic.

Comment: This will surely work but it’s still strictly worse than having a label tag for accessibility and enlarging the clickable area of the checkbox. My answer suffers from the same problem because I omitted the `for` attrib for brevity, but definitely go with a label.

Answer (score 0):

> **Important notes**
>
> I don't have label to append text on it

```js
$(subClassesContainer).append('<input type="checkbox" class="subclassCheckbox" name="selectedSubClasses" value="' + item.subClassAccountId + '" /> ' + item.subClassAccountName + '<br />');
```

I’m assuming `item.subClassAccountName` is the string you want to push into `selectedClassText` if its checkbox is selected.

Since it is not inside an element, this is needlessly difficult. Put it inside a `<label>` and your original code should work:

```js
$(subClassesContainer).append('<input type="checkbox" class="subclassCheckbox" name="selectedSubClasses" value="' + item.subClassAccountId + '" /> <label>' + item.subClassAccountName + '</label><br />');
```

Because this code looks for the *element* immediately following the checkbox, but only if it is a label.

```js
selectedClassText.push($(this).next('label').text());
```

It will stop working if you put anything in between the checkbox and the label.